# How to enable program to dump core on linux?

Tags: c, linux, coredump

I want the program to dump core on crash on Linux for debugging purpose. How do I enable this feature - does this require any changes in the program ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either enable it for yourself by doing:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

If you want this to be persistent put it in ~/.profile

Alterantively, you can enable core dumps for all users on the system put the following line in /etc/sercurity/limits.conf (at least on ubuntu):

```
*   0  core    -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether generate core dump or not is controlled by the shell

If you use bash.

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Answer (score 2):

If your program is user-mode program. Here is a brief tutorial.

**Set the core file size to maximum**

> ulimit -c unlimited

**Run your program**

> $  ./your_program
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It would generate core dump file.
Use gdb to analyze the core dump

> gdb ./your_progrm core

You can reference [How to Debug Using GDB](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Troy's answer you will have to add to e/etc/sysctl.conf - where and how you need to core to be generated - 
like this :

```
kernel.core_uses_pid=1
kenrel.core_pattern= /tmp/cores/core-%e-%p-%u-%g-%s-%t
fs.suid_dumpable=2
```

Comment: You can do that, but I believe most Linux distributions would dump a `core` file in the current directory if nothing has been specifically configured (so saying "you will have to" is a bit too strong, "you may have to" would be enough)