# Why a JRE crashes because of core dumping?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

My JRE crashed when executing a shared library function called from java code via JNI. The output says that JRE crashed because it "Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled.". 
After many days googling without explanation, my questions is:

1. Where can I find info about JRE core dumping? I want to understand the problem and the solution.

I know the output recommends executing "ulimit -c unlimited" and this questions proposes solutions ([How to enable program to dump core on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832615/how-to-enable-program-to-dump-core-on-linux))

Here I've pasted the JRE output:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7e541cec55, pid=20390, tid=140180586714880
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libXXX.so+0x1fc55]  NewMask_UnsetAll+0x15
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /XXX/hs_err_pid20390.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: Since this question is 17 days old, is this error still unresolved?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question…

This message "Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled." didn't mean this was the cause of the crash. The word "Failed" is indeed misleading here.

This message only means that [core dumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) are disabled in the Java VM (which is usually the case), so that such dumps are not produced in case of crash.